# Невозможно вытащить данные из сессии

Tags: webmoney, сессия, php

Такой вопрос для знатоков сервиса вебмани трансфер. Интегрирую его с интернет магазином. Почему невозможно вытащить данные из сессии, когда сервис вебмани трансфер передает предварительный пост-запрос на сайт. Когда я напрямую обращаюсь к странице с этим кодом  - все прекрасно вытаскивается, а когда вебмани обращается к этому скрипту, то данные сесии не вытаскиваются. Сессия существует. Но пишет Notice: Undefined index: order_id (это имя ключа).

Что это может быть?

Comment: Смотрите какой ключ сессии передает веб мани(99% что никакого).

Comment: @ToRcH565, а вебмани должен передавать какой-то ключ сессии? я просто немного не доганяю о чем речь. я имелл ввиду почему не вытаскиваются данные сессии, которые Я установил

Comment: @ToRcH565, дошло... а как быть тогда...? куки тоже не помагают..

Comment: @ToRcH565, придумал. спасибо за наводки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что нужен ключ сессии, который вы отдаете браузеру при первой установке и получаете при каждом запросе страницы(ваш скрипт). и без этого ключа каждый раз новая сессия будет.